# passing two parameters in batch file not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to pass two parameter to a batch file which will verify if the filename is available or not. I am having trouble running the code below as I need the batch file to prompt the required message if one of the two parameters is false.

Any help please?

```dos
@echo off

echo.
if "%1" == "" if "%2" == "" (
    echo Syntaxe : parameters required
    exit /B 1
)

if EXIST %1 (
    echo %1 exist
) ELSE (
    echo file: %1 does not exist
)

if EXIST %2 (
    echo %2 exist
) ELSE (
    echo file: %2 does not exist
)
```

Comment: [DOS and cmd are very different things](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's no such thing as `exit /b` in DOS

Comment: You would need to tell us what you expect this code to do and what it actually does on your system and the parameters that you are providing.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] and [ASK], you haven't told us how your script deviates from your expectations. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I am trying to pass two parameters to a batch file so that it verifies if the file exists. If no parameter is passed, it will display "Syntax: parameters required". If the file exists it will display the file name, else it will display filename does not exist. Thanks

Comment: Here in this case my parameter is some file which exist in the same folder as the batch file. if i pass only one filename to the batch file it displays that the filename exists and an error message as "The syntax of the command is incorrect." I expected the batch file to prompt me that it needs a second parameter, which is not the case in the above code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if "%1" == "" if "%2" == ""
```

checks that *both* `%1` and `%2` are empty. What you want to do is check them one by one, so that you exit the script if *either* `%1` or `%2` is empty.

```
if "%1" == "" (
  echo This script requires two parameters.
  goto :eof
)
if "%2" == "" (
  echo This script requires two parameters.
  goto :eof
)
```

To avoid writing the same code twice, the recommended solution is to isolate it as an error routine:

```
if "%1" == "" goto :emptyarg
if "%2" == "" goto :emptyarg
...
goto :eof
:emptyarg
echo This script requires two parameters
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution ALexP. I tried with the following code below and it works

    @echo off

    echo.
    if "%1" == "" if "%2" == "" (
    echo This script requires two parameters
    exit /B 1
    )
    if NOT "%1" == "" if "%2" == "" (
    This script requires two parameters
    exit /B 1
    )
    if "%1" == "" if NOT "%2" == "" (
    echo This script requires two parameters
    exit /B 1
    )

    if NOT "%1" == "" if NOT "%2" == "" (
    echo Two parameters are present
    exit /B 1
    )

Comment: you can safely omit the `if "%1"` line. If `%2` is empty, there are not enough (zero or one only) parameters - no need to check for `%1`. Also for proper handling it would be safer to use `if "%~2" (avoid double-quoting, when `%2` already has quotes)